# Bootstrap 3 Datepicker v4 Docs 24 hours time format

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ and is it possible to cofigure to use 24 hours format?

Nowadays I use it like this but it is not what I need

```
$('.dayWorkTime').datetimepicker({
    format: 'LT' 
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you have to set [`format`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#format) to `HH:mm`.

As the docs says:

> See [momentjs' docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) for valid formats. Format also dictates what components are shown, e.g. MM/dd/YYYY will not display the time picker.

Here a working example:

```js
$("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
  format: 'HH:mm'
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```